# TimedRotatingFileHandler in logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have the following code:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('log_', when='midnight')
root_logger.addHandler(fh)

logging.error('This is an error message')
```

Expected output -- file with name "log_2014-06-20", but I've got "log_". Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The time is applied when rotation happens, not before. If you use a filename of e.g. `myapp.log`, that name will be used until rollover, when it will be renamed using a time-based suffix and a new file created called `myapp.log`. The new file is then logged to until the *next* rollover.